# CDO Classic ASP form not working

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have a form that was working for me but i made some amendments and i can figure out why it is now working. I was hoping someone could help. I have changed the SMTP to 0's. My code:

```
<%  
submitter = request.form("submitter")
dotty = request.form("would you like a confirmation email")
appno = request.form("application number")
cust = request.form("customer name")
broker = request.form("broker name")
company = request.form("company")
introtel = request.form("broker contact number")
sdate = request.form("date of call")
stime = request.form("time of call")
sreason = request.form("reason")


Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")  

With cdoConfig.Fields  
    .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort  
    .Item(cdoSMTPServer) = "00.000.00.000"  
    .Update  
End With 

Set cdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")  

With cdoMessage 
    Set .Configuration = cdoConfig 
    .From = submitter
    .To = "Me@me.co.uk"
    .Subject = Callback request
    .TextBody = "Advisors Name: " & submitter & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Application Number: " & appno & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Customer Name: " & cust & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Broker Name: " & broker & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Company: " & company & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Broker Contact Number: " & introtel & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Date of Call: " & sdate & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Time of Call: " & stime & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Reason for Escalation: " & sreason 
    .Send 
End With 

Set cdoMessage = Nothing  
Set cdoConfig = Nothing  

Response.write "<HTML><head><title></title></head><body><body bgcolor=""#161712"" TEXT=""white"" ALINK=""white"" VLINK=""white""><center><br><br><Br><Br><Br><br><br><br><Br><br><Br><br>Your request has been submitted....<br><br><br><a href = ""javascript:window.close();""> Click here to close window </a> </center></body></HTML>"

%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed the quotation marks in your subject: "Callback Request".

Comment: Thats brilliant. Excellent attention to detail. Thanks dude. It wont let me mark it as answered for 11 mins but i will as soon as i can.